# Smart Card Validation Pin Error 0x80100001

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, smartcard, gemalto

I'm using gemalto usb token and SafeNet software to digitally sign my documents in Adobe Acrobat Pro. While everything worked fine and nothing has changed, I'm getting this error after entering my (correct) pin number. The message says: 'Error occurred during PIN validation'. According to a[uthentication return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-return-values), it is related to:

> SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR: An internal consistency check failed.

Besides that, 'Validating Signatures' option in Adobe is disabled.

Thank you!

[image: Error with code:0x80100001]

Comment: Can you verify the PIN successfully in any other application? If not, reinstalling SafeNet may be worth a try.

Comment: That was the cause! After reinstalling and installing SafeNet again everything worked fine, thank you @guidot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody else encountering a similar problem: The error code is by PCSC, and so not necessarily card-related.

If other applications are also unable to verify the PIN, issue might be caused by reader driver, or as in the case above by any software required for accessing the card [here: SafeNet]. Re-installing those is worth a ttry.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

On a new PC couldn't use this token.

I checked how windows recognized the device on a different one where worked fine. Seems like the culprit is a newer driver from microsoft.

All I had to do was to replace it. Visit [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=Gemalto+IDPrime) and click:

> **"Gemalto IDPrime - SmartCard - 10/20/2017 12:00:00 AM - 8.5.0.7  Windows 10 Creators Update and Later Servicing Drivers"**

- Download the cab file.
- Extract it.
- Next you have to "update" the driver with the old one.